# 60 point CMPT Sci

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

Write a program that first generates 100 random numbers in the range [11, 25] and store them in a file named “random.txt”. Write just one number in each row.  Then open and read data from the file “random.txt”. Calculate the average of all the 100 number and count how many times the number 16 occurs. Using only one single loop in this step. That is, update the running total and the occurrence of 16 during each repetition of the loop. The sample file and output are given below.

Hint: To generate a random integer in a range [min,max, use the following statement

rand()%(max-min+1)+min;

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 0):

**>>Write a program that first generate 100 random numbers in the range [11, 25] and store them in a file named “random.txt”.**

C++ provides the following classes to perform output and input of characters to/from files: 
ofstream: Stream class to write on files
ifstream: Stream class to read from files
fstream: Stream class to both read and write from/to files.

I suggest you could try to use ofstream to write the random numbers to “random.txt” file.

Here is the code:

```
    cout << "Now writing data to the file." << endl;
    ofstream OutFile("random.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    OutFile << rand() % (25 - 11 + 1) + 11 << '\n';
    OutFile.close();
    cout << "Done with the writing." << endl;
```

**>>Then open and read data from the file “random.txt”. Calculate the average of all the 100 number**

We could use [fopen_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-s-wfopen-s?view=vs-2019)to open the file. And then we can use [fscanf_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fscanf-s-fscanf-s-l-fwscanf-s-fwscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019) to read formatted data from stream.

Here is the code:

```
    cout << "Now reading deta fron the file." << endl;
    int n, r;
    double d, sum;
    FILE *f;
    fopen_s(&f,"random.txt", "r");
    n = 0;
    sum = 0.0;
    while (1) {
        r = fscanf_s(f, "%lf", &d);
        if (1 == r) 
        {
            sum += d;
            n++;
        }
        else if (0 == r) {
            fscanf_s(f, "%*c");
        }
        else break;
    }
    fclose(f);
    cout << "average value=" << sum / n << endl;
```

**>> count how many times the number 16 occurs**

We could read numbers line by line, if the number is equal to "16", "sum1" plus "1".

Here is my code:

```
    int sum1 = 0;
    ifstream infile("random.txt");
    int number;
    infile >> number;
    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        if (number == 16)
        {
            sum1++;
        }
        infile >> number;
    }
    cout << "The number 16 appears " << sum1 << " times in the file" << endl;
```